# In need of better structure in jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, coding-style, structure

I have an extremely simple jQuery animation program that will effect the visibility of some tabs stacked over top of each other. The functionality is fine no complaints, yet the structure of my code is horrendous. My codes repeating the same function over and over and yet i am unable to write a function that can carry out the task quite the same. I want to include a low level amount of encapsulation if possible because i would like to be able to use this in an example. Below is the code.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
                    if($(window).scrollTop()>450){
                        last.slideDown(700, function(){
                        third.slideDown(700, function(){
                        second.slideDown(700, function(){
                        first.slideDown(700);
                        })})})
                    }
                    else{
                        bars.slideUp(1000);
                    }   
                });


                first.mouseenter(function(){    //when first elements hovered over
                    second.animate({opacity : ".4"},{ duration:500, queue:false});
                    third.animate({opacity : ".4"},{ duration:500, queue:false});
                    last.animate({opacity : ".4"},{ duration:500, queue:false});

                    first.mouseleave(function(){
                        second.animate({opacity : "1"},{duartion:50, queue:false});
                        third.animate({opacity : "1"},{duartion:50, queue:false});
                        last.animate({opacity : "1"},{duartion:50, queue:false});

                    })  
                })          
                second.mouseenter(function(){   //when second elements hovered over
                    second.css("z-index", "5");
                    first.animate({opacity : ".4"},{ duration:500, queue:false});
                    third.animate({opacity : ".4"},{ duration:500, queue:false});
                    last.animate({opacity : ".4"},{ duration:500, queue:false});

                    second.mouseleave(function(){
                        second.css("z-index", "3");
                        first.animate({opacity : "1"},{duartion:50, queue:false});
                        third.animate({opacity : "1"},{duartion:50, queue:false});
                        last.animate({opacity : "1"},{duartion:50, queue:false});

                    })  
                })
                    third.mouseenter(function(){    //second element hover
                    third.css("z-index", "4");
                    first.animate({opacity : ".4"},{ duration:500, queue:false});
                    second.animate({opacity : ".4"},{ duration:500, queue:false});
                    last.animate({opacity : ".4"},{ duration:500, queue:false});

                    third.mouseleave(function(){    //third element hover
                        third.css("z-index", "2");
                        first.animate({opacity : "1"},{duartion:50, queue:false});
                        second.animate({opacity : "1"},{duartion:50, queue:false});
                        last.animate({opacity : "1"},{duartion:50, queue:false});                   
                    })  
                })
                last.mouseenter(function(){     //last element hover
                    last.css("z-index", "4");
                    first.animate({opacity : ".4"},{ duration:500, queue:false});
                    third.animate({opacity : ".4"},{ duration:500, queue:false});
                    second.animate({opacity : ".4"},{ duration:500, queue:false});

                    last.mouseleave(function(){
                        last.css("z-index", "1");
                        first.animate({opacity : "1"},{duartion:50, queue:false});
                        third.animate({opacity : "1"},{duartion:50, queue:false});
                        second.animate({opacity : "1"},{duartion:50, queue:false});                     
                    })  
                })
            });
```

Comment: Why are you binding `mouseleave` handlers from *inside* your `mouseenter` handler? If the user moves the mouse in and out several times you'll end up with several `mouseleave` handlers on the same element. (Also, this question might be better placed on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.)

Comment: while the script is being executed for when the user is hovering over it i need it still listening for when the user scrolls out of it. If you canprovide another method id be happy to use it.

Comment: Just declare the `mouseleave` handlers *outside* the `mouseenter` handlers.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you put first, second, third and last variable in an array and iterate through the array instead of using the real name? The pattern that you have written fits if you put your variable in an array and use these array's elements.